# Radiation through optical windows

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, optics, radiation

Problem I'm interested in solving: How much radiative heat load is entering the system through optical windows (in SI units - Watts)? (see the images below)

I have tried to break the problem into its most basic components. We have a series of 4 boxes, one inside the other.The boxes themselves are radiation shields and so should have very little radiation entering through them. Can consider it negligible as the windows are the focus of the question.

They are not in thermal contact with each other and there is a gap between each one (in reality the top of the boxes are connected to something else and not floating in air!).

The outer box has a window on each side (except top and bottom). The diameter of the windows are 50mm and 3mm thick.

The 2nd and 3rd boxes have holes in each side to allow light to travel through (eg. if you wanted, you could shine a laser through and into the inner box).

The inner box also has windows on each side. The diameter is 10mm and the thickness is 1mm. Each box is at a different temperature.

The outer box is exposed to ambient temperature around it (293K is a fine approximation). The 2nd box is at 50K. The 3rd box is 4K. The inner box is 2K. There is a vacuum inside the boxes.

How many watts makes it through the 2nd window (where I might have a sample of some sort)?

Some other info:
The windows are in thermal contact with the boxes and thus the same temperature. The boxes are aluminium and the windows are Zinc Selenide. However, any material could be used for the calculation. I want to know how it was done and what properties of the material were used. For Zinc Selenide, I was using an emissivity of $0.88$. It transmits $75$ percent of light (approximation) between $0.6\mu m$ and $21\mu m$ wavelength range.

To try solve this, I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that only the windows need to be considered. I tried to use the Stefan-Boltzman law but the answer I get seems suspiciously low. Window 2 answer is tiny. I feel I'm missing some key consideration needed to solve the problem.I tried to put all info in the drawing below even if I'm not using everything in the calculation.

Stefan-Boltzman Law (with transmissivity term):
\begin{equation}
    P = \tau \epsilon \sigma A (T_1^4 - T_2^4)
\end{equation}
Emissivity $\epsilon = 0.88$

Stefan-Boltzman Constant $\sigma = 5.67 \times 10^{-8}$

A = Area

Transmissivity $\tau = 0.75$

Window 1 (Outer)

Radius = $\phi / 2 = 0.05 / 2 = 0.025 m$

Area = $\pi (0.025)^2 = 0.00196 m^2$

\begin{equation}
    P_1 = \tau \epsilon \sigma A (T_1^4 - T_2^4)  
    =  (0.75) (0.88)(5.67 \times 10^{-8}) (0.00196) (293)^4 
    = 0.541 W  
\end{equation}

Window 2 (Inner)

Radius = $\phi / 2 = 0.01 / 2 = 0.005 m$

Area = $\pi (0.005)^2 = 0.000079 m^2$

\begin{equation}
    P_2 = \tau \epsilon \sigma A (T_1^4 - T_2^4) 
    = (0.75) (0.88)(5.67 \times 10^{-8}) (0.000079) (2)^4
    = 4.73 \times 10^{-11} W
\end{equation}

At this point I'm stuck as it seems something is wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Transmissivity =0.75.   .... is the missing 0.25 light reflected or absorbed?

Comment: I'm not too sure. I have values for the absortion coefficient at various wavelengths for this material but don't know how it applies. I thought that the amount of transmission was what was key. Even if I assume worst case serario and all the light is transmited, the answer is still very small.

Comment: https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=3981&gad_source=1&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIzuGhrvTqhAMVtwetBh1kjgFVEAAYAyAAEgLQNvD_BwE

Comment: Thor labs is a good source of specs for optical!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.